# Get the file name as a string in Rust

Tags: error-handling, rust, compiler-errors, path, filenames

I am trying to get the file name of a given string using the following code:

```rust
fn get_filename() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let file = "folder/file.text";
    let path = Path::new(file);
    let filename = path.file_name()?.to_str()?;
    println!("{}",filename);
    Ok(())
}
```

But I get this error:

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `std::io::Error`
```

The original code didn't want to return `Result`, but that's the only way to use `?`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Niklas's answer here is the answer:

```
fn filename() -> Option<()> {
    let file = "hey.text";
    let path = Path::new(file);
    let filename = path.file_name()?.to_str()?;
    println!("{}",filename);
    None
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `.file_name()` and `.to_str()` here return an `Option`. The usage of the `?` operator on the `None` variant to convert to an `Err` is an experimental feature (see [the `NoneError` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/struct.NoneError.html)). If you want to use the `?` operator, you could consider returning `Option<()>` here or unwrapping the result by hand.